# Why was there an alien/creature being autopsied in Peru?

Tags: indiana-jones, kingdom-of-the-crystal-skull

In Indiana Jones and the Kingdom of the Crystal Skull, after Mutt and Indy get caught when they found the crystal skull, Spalko and her men take them to their camp in the jungles of Peru.

There, she showed Indiana that there were creatures that had skeletons made of pure quartz crystal and she showed a recently autopsied creature and his skull was indeed like the one Indy and Mutt found at the burial site.

Why did they bring an autopsied alien into the jungles of Peru? It's hardly sanitary and a secret like that wouldn't be safe in a location that public. Did they perform the autopsy there? Why wasn't it done at a secret base in the Soviet Union and kept top secret?

Comment: Kingdom of the Crystal...? I don't know what you're talking about, there are only 3 movies....

Comment: I thought there was just one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Irina_Spalko), and also [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345501284) (I''d really rather not type in sections of the book), Irina Spalko had set the entire operation in Peru up not only for the purpose of study, but to lure Indiana Jones there and compel him to help her cause.

> In fact, in the South American jungle, Spalko had arranged for Jones’
>   former lover, Marion Ravenwood Williams, and his former colleague,
>   Harold Oxley, to be captured and held prisoner. The intent of this was
>   to lure Jones to Nazca in search of his two friends, so that Spalko
>   could recapture the troublesome American.

With that as the motivation, she would want the bodies there to be able to show Indy her research. The autopsies weren't performed on site.

> As it were, a few years prior two alien spacecraft had crashed in
>   Russia, the beings inside killed from the impact. These creatures
>   shared a very peculiar trait: skeletons made of a magnetic,
>   psychically-supercharged crystal, with abnormally long skulls and
>   massive eye sockets. Both were examined and given autopsies by Soviet
>   scientists, and Spalko was a member of the team that studied the
>   bodies.